# Unable to get fileDetails part when using YouTube videos API

Tags: api, youtube

I am trying to get a list of videos from YouTube using YouTube API. I am using an API key. When  I use the URL below everything works fine and I get the desired results:
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=id%2Csnippet%2CcontentDetails&id=I6zuKbBlmRo&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

But when I add fileDetails to the part parameter, I get a 403 forbidden error with this response:
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=id%2Csnippet%2CcontentDetails%2CfileDetails&id=I6zuKbBlmRo&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

**403 Forbidden**

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

From YouTube APIv3 Docs:

```
    The **fileDetails** object encapsulates information about the video file that was   
    uploaded to YouTube, including the file's resolution, duration, audio and video 
    codecs, stream bitrates, and more. **This data can only be retrieved by the video owner.**
```

Only the owner can get those properties.

Comment: Hi I am owner of video. so How can we authenticate for same apart from apikey. I have json key but I don't know how to attach in url