# How do i get the list of all videos from youtube using gdata python library

Tags: python, api, youtube

I was referring to this doc.
https://developers.google.com/youtube/1.0/developers_guide_python#SearchingVideos

this explains the various operations for youtube

but i am not getting how do i get all the videos from the youtube channel

i need to get all video list title,url and the thumbnail for that video

any help would be appreciated

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

got the answer from the doc itself, in case if anybody need it.

```
yt_service = gdata.youtube.service.YouTubeService()
yt_service.ssl = True

yt_service.developer_key = 'xxx'
yt_service.client_id = 'xxx'

yt_service.email = 'xxx@dd.com'
yt_service.password = 'xxx'
yt_service.source = 'youtube'
yt_service.ProgrammaticLogin()
videos = yt_service.GetYouTubeVideoFeed("https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/uploads")
```

and then

```
 for video in videos.entry
     print video
```

Comment: Please accept your answer by clicking on the tick mark on the left side. This helps other users too.

Answer (score 2):

There are many other questions on SO that may help you. Here is a list of some of them:

[Retrieve all videos from youtube playlist using youtube v3 API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18804904/retrieve-all-videos-from-youtube-playlist-using-youtube-v3-api)

[YouTube API Return List of All Videos from Specific Category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19510801/youtube-api-return-list-of-all-videos-from-specific-category)

[How do I get a YouTube video thumbnail from the YouTube API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068344/how-do-i-get-a-youtube-video-thumbnail-from-the-youtube-api?rq=1)

[Unable to get fileDetails part when using YouTube videos API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17180550/unable-to-get-filedetails-part-when-using-youtube-videos-api)

[How to extract the title of a youtube video using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8738916/how-to-extract-the-title-of-a-youtube-video-using-python)

[python: get all youtube video urls of a channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15512239/python-get-all-youtube-video-urls-of-a-channel)

I hope it was helpful.