# YouTube Data API: 403 forbidden error when accessing videos endpoint

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

When I try to request infos about a video via the YouTube Data API, I always get a 403 forbidden error:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id={video_id}&key={my_key}&part=snippet,contentDetails,statistics,status,fileDetails
```

Error message:

```
{
    "error": {
        "errors": [
            {
                "domain": "youtube.common",
                "reason": "forbidden",
                "message": "Forbidden"
            }
        ],
        "code": 403,
        "message": "Forbidden"
    }
}
```

I have not restricted any referrers for my key, and the key is valid. Does anybody now why this is not working? I think I sticked to the docs at

- https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#try-it

If I omit the `fileDetails` part, the request resolves fine. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can only request part "fileDetails" if you are the owner.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17180550/unable-to-get-filedetails-part-when-using-youtube-videos-api

Comment: Comment from IanS should be the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Currently this is nowhere stated in the docs, at least not at the endpoint's docs at https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list Can you give me a reference please? As I'm mostly interested in the file size of an item, is there any other way to get this?